# How to debug a specific binary using VS Code on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, debugging, visual-studio-code

I want to debug a Python binary which then calls scipy C++ modules (I want to step those) as suggested [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/hacking.html). I can successfully do that with command line gdb using

```
gdb --args python runtests.py -g --python mytest.py
```

and I can do the same in eclipse by setting the binary as:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

and debugger's arguments as

```
runtests.py -g --python mytest.py
```

Can I do this somehow in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I created a new launch configuration in launch.json file (by clicking on the Configure gear icon in the debugger), set program to

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

args to

```
runtests.py -g --python mytest.py
```

and added

```
"break" : "NI_ZoomShift"
```

to setupCommands. Then just run the new configuration which is in my case called (gdb) scipy and it works.

[image: launch.json]

[This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) link has been very helpful.